# Installing External Python Module using Command Line - No Command Supplied

Tags: python, python-3.x, command-line, windows-7, command-prompt

I am trying to install a python module *manually* without `pip` or `easy_install` in Python 3. At first I tried (after `cd` to the folder containing the `setup.py` file):

```
python setup.py install
```

However, I recieved an error:

> 'python' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

After [a little research](https://docs.python.org/2/install/#the-new-standard-distutils), I realised that without the `python` it should work:

```
setup.py install
```

This also gave me an error:

> error: no command supplied

More [researching](https://superuser.com/questions/222957/no-commands-supplied-error-when-executing-a-python-script-on-ubuntu) told me to go back to `python setup.py install` (which doesn't work), and following these [instructions and following links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13270877/how-to-manually-install-a-pypi-module-without-pip-easy-install) hasn't worked either.

I would appreciate any help in installing this module (the module being `BeautifulSoup4`).

Comment: command is like `python,` not `Python.` Please correct it

Comment: why are you not using pip?

Comment: @Odedra I still get the same problem. Updating the question now.

Comment: windows is case insensitive so uppercase  would not matter, do you have a `C://Python3` directory

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I've tried using pip and it doesn't seem like it has been bundled with my version of Python. Using Pip in Python Command Line gives me `invalid syntax` (I assume I have to use it in _Python_ command line?)

Comment: what error are you getting, also if you are trying to install a python 3 package you would have to use the python3 interpreter with the setup.py script

Comment: @PadraicCunningham do you mean to run it in the Python Shell that comes with IDLE? Right now I've tried using Run.exe (just running the setup.py) and Command Line (as above). I don't have a `C://Python3` directory, the closest is `C:\Python34`, which is what I have been using.

Comment: No I meant if you have python2.7 and 3.4 installed you will have to specify the correct interpreter . C:\Python34 is fine I just wanted to make sure you had some python 3 installed. Do you have `C:\Python34 ` in your PATH?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This probably means your `python.exe` is not in your `PATH`.

Invoking `setup.py` directly works because of Windows' file associations.

The [Python manual actually has an entry on how to set up your PATH](https://docs.python.org/2/using/windows.html#excursus-setting-environment-variables), but its instructions are for Windows < 7, so here goes:

1. Hit Windows+PAUSE to bring up the System Properties dialog.
2. Click Advanced System Settings.
3. Click Environment Variables.
4. Add `;C:\Python3;C:\Python3\Scripts` (or wherever your Python is) to the PATH environment variable (preferably in the System variables section). It's handy to have the `Scripts` directory in there too, to be able to easily run `pip` and other scripts.
5. OK out through all the dialog boxes.
6. Open a new command prompt (PATH changes do not always propagate automatically into open command prompts).
7. Try `python`. Should work.