# How to bundle Python module without publishing it?

Tags: python, python-2.7, bundle, module-packaging

I have downloaded a Python module from

http://www.piersharding.com/download/python/sapnwrfc/

I have built it and it works fine. Now I want to use the same module on another machine. I read a bit through Python bundling and how to publish a module so that other developers can install it with easy_install or pip. But this is not what I want. It is not my module so I won't publish it on the real author's behalf. I just don't want to build everything again and again every time I want to use it on another machine.

The folder structure is

```
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/
    ...
    [a lot of other unrelated stuff]
    ...
    sapnwrfc-0.19.egg-info
    nwsaprfcutil.so
    sapnwrfc/
        __init__.py
        __init__.pyc
        rfc/
            __init__.py
            __init__.pyc
```

There are a couple of classes in the __init__.py modules but it looks like the main code is in the shared library. So of course I could copy the relevant parts over to a target machine (provided the platform fits the platform of the so module) but I can hardly believe this is the proper way to do it.
Can someone help?

Comment: This should help you > https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13270877/how-to-manually-install-a-pypi-module-without-pip-easy-install

Comment: Why can't you build it on the other machine?

Comment: I can build on another machine but packaging and easily deployable modules seem to be a good software engineering practice. You don't build every software package on every machine you want to use it, do you? In addition, on most Windows machines there is no compiler...