# Python: How to properly set up boto3 and connect to AWS S3?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto, boto3

I walked through the following:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-chap-getting-started.html
https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide/quickstart.html#installation

And came up with the file (pract.py) using an IDE:

```
import boto3

# Let's use Amazon S3
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')

for bucket in s3.buckets.all():
    print(bucket.name)
```

And ran it but came across the following error even though I installed the boto3:

```
ImportError: No module named boto3
```

How can I confirm everything has been installed and configured correctly? What could be the issue?

Thank you in advance and will be sure to accept/upvote answer

**WHEN I DO pip install boto3**

[image]

Comment: Can you post the STDOUT from when you ran `pip install boto3`?

Comment: @Jared please take a look at the original post for screenshot

Comment: Are you running your script from within the IDE?  Or at the command line?

Answer (score 2):

Did you install via pip? Run the command

```
pip list
```

See if the list that is output contains boto3, otherwise, you can follow these instructions:

[How to manually install a pypi module without pip/easy_install?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13270877/how-to-manually-install-a-pypi-module-without-pip-easy-install)

to install boto3 from the zip file downloaded from this link:

https://github.com/boto/boto3

Comment: Tried it and I see boto3 (1.4.4) yet still getting `ImportError: No module named boto3`

Comment: if I were you, I would uninstall boto3 via pip (pip uninstall boto3) and then install the package manually from the link provided. You may have setup your paths incorrectly when you installed python/pip.

Comment: What I did was sudo apt install python3-pip, then pip3 install boto3. By default, my shell environment launches python 3.5 (aliased via .bashrc). I was able to resolve the no module named boto3, and s3 = boto3.resource('s3')