# How to install Python Modules

Tags: python

I want to install pyserial for python, but I don't know how. I have tried stuff like pip, but it doesn't recognise the install command. How do I install it?

Comment: Please, provide the command you used to install pyserial, and the error log

Comment: Also your operating system and its version.

Answer (score 1):

First you have to install pip  [follow this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4750806/how-do-i-install-pip-on-windows) .Then you can use `pip install pyserial`

Or you can download pyserial from [gituhub](https://github.com/pyserial/pyserial) and run `python setup.py install`

Answer (score 0):

How about your python version? The default version of python is 2.x. If you want to use python 3 then install it with [pyenv](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv) to control your python version.

I think it would be easier for you to solve this problem if you are using windows. Simple install python3 and pip is automatically there. All you need to do is

```
pip install pyserial
```

or

```
pip3 install pyserial
```

About how to install python3 on windows:

[install python3 on windows](https://www.howtogeek.com/197947/how-to-install-python-on-windows/)

Good luck!

Answer (score -2):

in terminal use `python -m pip install 'packagename'`

in python shell try

```
import pip
pip.main(['install','pyserial'])
```

or download the module and use `python setup.py pyserial`

( [How to manually install a pypi module without pip/easy_install?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13270877/how-to-manually-install-a-pypi-module-without-pip-easy-install) )

Comment: although you downvoted this  i stand by this answer to the fullest extent :)