# Pip isnt working python 3.6

Tags: python, pip

I'm learning python right now. I installed Pip and everything seemed correct in the instalation but when I executed any command from Pip such as pip install (path) it gave errors such as:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "", line 1, in

or

> SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Can anyone help me please?

Comment: What did you try to install with `pip`?

Comment: try, `pip install --upgrade pip`

Comment: You're running pip commands in the Python shell! Do it in the regular command prompt or terminal!

Comment: @manvi77 So I can start working with paths.

Comment: @AshrafulIslam Already tryed

Comment: Had the same trouble.  For people new to python, it's not clear at all from the docs that you need to do this from a normal command prompt.

Answer (score 0):

For other people running into this problem all i did was
`pkg update` than `pkg install clang` this is for Linux and Termux.

For windows it will be `npm update` than `npm install clang`

incase you use `yarn` than `yarn update` than `yarn add clang`

Answer (score -1):

in terminal use `python -m pip install 'packagename'`

in python shell try

```
import pip
pip.main(['install','packagename'])
```

replace *packagename* with the package you want to install

or download the module and use `python setup.py packagename`

( [How to manually install a pypi module without pip/easy_install?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13270877/how-to-manually-install-a-pypi-module-without-pip-easy-install) )