# Unable to install elastic beanstalk AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am setting up a aws server for Django Server. I have successfully installed python3.5.1, pip and django.

Following aws documentation i am running the following command :

> pip install awsebcli

I get this Error:

```
Collecting awsebcli
  Using cached awsebcli-3.12.4.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-build-1eejewt6/awsebcli/setup.py", line 46, in <module>
        long_description=open('README.rst').read() + open('CHANGES.rst').read(),
      File "/usr/lib/python3.5/encodings/ascii.py", line 26, in decode
        return codecs.ascii_decode(input, self.errors)[0]
    UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 4092: ordinal not in range(128)

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-1eejewt6/awsebcli/
```

like error occurs when trying to opean and read rst files.

Eb repo can be found [here](https://pypi.python.org/packages/45/fd/f0f7ff9cba9a2ab803881d7d910ea06985834eee5ce28a09329b6c1a51e3/awsebcli-3.12.4.tar.gz) . I tried fixing the error in package and run manually but no success. Why is there an error in official repo? Am i missing something?

Comment: add the command line option --upgrade to your pip install command. This will upgrade the awsebcli dependencies.

Comment: i did that too, same error

Comment: FYI: check this [AWS forums](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=276563&tstart=0) post out. This appears to be a problem on some operating environments.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I manually installed an older version (3.10.0) located [here](https://pypi.python.org/packages/23/f6/b73be78b302037e3bbc01c3be9d8d3936e2fc4a61087d6fb41018c420b07/awsebcli-3.10.0.tar.gz) and this one is working fine.

Comment: You can also install it with `pip3 install awsebcli==3.10.0`

Comment: This is a workaround, but one one cannot stick forever with old versions. Answer of Nikhil Prakash should be the accepted one.

Answer (score 3):

In awsebcli package for version >= 3.10.3, some changes were added in CHANGES.rst which had a unicode character 'ã' on Line 156. This is causing the mentioned error while installing in some os versions.

If awsebcli version >= 3.10.3 is required, then install the package the manually till there is no official resolution from aws.

Follow [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13270877/how-to-manually-install-a-pypi-module-without-pip-easy-install/13271241#13271241) of how to install a package manually.

Before installing remove the unicode character in CHANGES.rst file.
It will work fine.

Comment: To remove the unicode character search for Sao Paolo in version 3.10.3 and make it just "So"

Answer (score 1):

From https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=897654&tstart=0 I decided to try

`export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8` and loading the README.rst and CHANGES.rst files no longer threw the encoding error. This avoids manually manipulating the package files.

Answer (score 0):

The error is in changes.rst and/or readme file. they are not required for the installation. so open the files, delete its contents and save. manually install it by going to the folder and executing `python setup.py install`

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I found that I had to install the setuptools first by doing `pip install setuptools` then the installation of awsebcli went successfully.