# No module named 'atom'

Tags: python, python-3.x, enaml

I am trying to run enaml-native create app for the first time, but I always get the error:

[image: No module named 'atom']

however I already have the module installed:

[image: output from: pip install atom]

Does anybody know how to fix this?

Comment: atom is installed in your /usr/ library, not in your anaconda environement. You can check the python path with ``print(sys.path)``

Comment: You can try installing atom without pip: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13270877/how-to-manually-install-a-pypi-module-without-pip-easy-install

Comment: It solved uninstalling and then install again some modules

Comment: Notice the first image is using Anaconda for searching for packages. The second is not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you should reinstall Atom:

```
pip uninstall atom
pip install atom
```

If that doesn't work, try `pip3` instead of `pip`:

And if those two don't work, try:

```
python -m pip uninstall atom
python -m pip install atom
```

If that doesn't work either, make sure you uninstall atom and then you can try installing it without pip:

[How to manually install a pypi module without pip/easy_install?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13270877/how-to-manually-install-a-pypi-module-without-pip-easy-install)

Comment: Well, I've just reinstalled as you said (again), and had issue with others modules, uninstall and reinstalled each of them and now It's solved. Thank you.