# How can PIP be installed on Python version 2.5.4 running in Windows 95 environment?

Tags: python, pip, setuptools, python-2.5, windows-95

**Context**

I'm constrained to using Python 2.5.4 in a Windows 95 environment and need PIP.  Those running versions earlier than 2.7.9 (after which PIP came pre-installed) are supposedly able to install PIP by following the instructions in this [link](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/).

**Obstacle**

Trouble is the file, [get-pip.py](https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py), referenced in the previous link is written with python 3 syntax, so at runtime it throws a host of SyntaxErrors in the 2.5.4 interpreter.

**What I've already tried**

I've managed to refactor get-pip.py, and it runs successfully up until it starts throwing more SyntaxErrors at the point where it executes the code derived from the binary blob, which I was unable to refactor.

Based on a suggestion in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13270877/how-to-manually-install-a-pypi-module-without-pip-easy-install), I've tried to install other libraries, including the PIP package manager, from their unzipped tar files [(link to compatible PIP tar)](https://pypi.org/project/pip/1.3/#files) via the included Setup.py script.  In PIP's case, this throws `ImportError: No module named setuptools`.  My attempt to remedy this by installing the compatible version of setuptools per the instructions [(link)](https://pypi.org/project/setuptools/0.8/#windows) for Windows failed because of a dependency with `socket.py`.  And so on, and so forth.

**Conclusion**

Is PIP even possible in Windows 95 with Python 2.5.4?  If someone were to help me stop hoping it were possible, I'd let it go and move on; but as it is I've spent 19 solid hours hoping to solve this puzzle with little to show for it.  Please help!

Comment: Try first getting `easy_install.exe` as in https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/easy_install.html#windows-executable-launcher, and once you have setuptools, do `easy_install pip`

Comment: given your openning statement you are aware that your O.S. is roughly 24 years old. Assuming you get past this hurdle, what about the next one. For example, what will you do with PIP once installed? chances are anything you install with it will also not work well on windows-95. At some point, it will be easier to just move on....

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, @dmitryro!  This was suggested in the instructions I referred to above; however, running ez_setup.py to generate the executable results in the dependency failure.  Thanks also @GMc for your reply!  Given the context I provided, it's wise advise.  I should elaborate that I aim to run python code to interface with legacy software that is not compatible on operating systems post Win-9X.  Most of the issues are not traced to the O.S. anyway.  If PIP is incompatible with 2.5.4, I'll abandon the objective; but I'm too persistent for my own good while the question is open.

Comment: Installing from PyPI or Github (you know how `pip` works, don't you?) will not work anyway because Python 2.5 is so old it doesn't work with modern OpenSSL and the current TLS protocols.