# python - Is it possible to create a project with dependencies in PyCharm?

Tags: python, pycharm, python-3.7

I have created a python project using PyCharm on my laptop and I want to get it into a VM which I do not have permissions to install anything using pip.

I am using libraries like pandas and numpy on my project, and on that VM I do not have those installed.

Is there any way to get my project working on that VM?

My project is implemented using Python 3.7 and Conda interpreter.

I have tried to install packages on that VM.

Comment: Create a Virtual Environment and activate virtual env on you VM.

Comment: You said you can't install anything on VM using pip right?

Comment: @DeepBhatt yes. I have tried to do it, and it does not allow me to do it.

Comment: @py_saad how can I do it?

Comment: If you can't do pip. Install pip on your VM

Comment: @py_saad, I can do pip, but I have no authorization to do it. It keeps on the same message until it stops ("Collecting package...").

Comment: Install pip and have a requirement.txt in which all your dependencies will be added. Later using python -m pip install -r requirement.txt

Comment: python -m pip install <package> --user Check if this works?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13270877/how-to-manually-install-a-pypi-module-without-pip-easy-install your answer lies in here. install package like this. Though, you still need administrative privileges  on VM for this

Comment: @py_saad, I have tried what you asked me to, and it did not worked.

Comment: @DeepBhatt, I will have a look on it. ;)

Comment: @py_saad, about the requirements.txt, I have also tried it, but it does exactly the same thing of when I just run "pip install ..."

Comment: Do you only want to run the script on the VM? if so, why not just compile it beforehand?