# Installing matplotlib and numpy without pip

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, module, installation

I'm running python 3.7 and idle.

I can't use pip because of the firewall at work (I think).

I tried following these instructions:

[How to manually install a pypi module without pip/easy_install?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13270877/how-to-manually-install-a-pypi-module-without-pip-easy-install)

When I try to install matplotlib it looks for numpy, so I assume it's a prerequisite.  numpy looks for VS c++ 14.0, so I assume that is also a prerequisite. Are my assumptions right?

Installing VS may be a pain due to hard drive space. I want to make sure I don't do it for nothing.

When I download and unzip the installation folders where is a good place to save them to make life easier?  I have a 'python37' folder in c drive and I created a new folder there. Is there somewhere better for referencing?

Please be as explicit as possible in your answers, all of this is new to me.

Comment: I would recommend you just get the your work’s proxy and use pip with that. I think it’ll be easier.

Comment: Maybe you could run Docker and get an image that ships with matplotlib...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have ability to download and install on your computer, I would recommend just installing/using the Anaconda distribution of Python, which has almost everything you need rolled in (including matplotlib and numpy) with the basics.

https://www.anaconda.com

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the work around is to set a proxy in . I have no idea where the proxy came from and why and how  it works but it worked.

I'd still be interested  to get answers to my questions though, as someone else might be having similar issues or needing to install downloaded modules on machines which aren't connected to the internet (the latter being very likely for me in the near future).

So to be clear I'm not asking what distribution to use or for other locations to download wheels files. I need to know how to install without using pip on a machine which is not connected to the internet.

Answer (score 0):

```
apt install python3-numpy
```

i Guess this will work

Answer (score -3):

Try downloading the packages from https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/ and install them using

```
pip install name_package.whl
```

Comment: The question title specifically says "without pip".