# Install numpy without pip

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, pip

I try to install numpy on my Windows 10, but I don't have pip.

Is there any way to install numpy without installing pip itself?

The reason I am asking is that I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57154622/installing-matplotlib-and-numpy-without-pip) related question, but I need to use the Python IDLE itself, because my code doesn't run in Jupyter Notebook.

Comment: I've found it most convenient to download `miniconda`, and use that framework to run pip and even ipython and jupyter.

Comment: Is there anything preventing you from installing `pip` itself? For instance, you can download https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py and then run `python get-pip.py`

Answer (score 1):

You can install any lib without pip using PyCharm IDE.
By following these steps in this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WcWyip8u4rI
Also you can install it using conda. this is the documentation:
https://numpy.org/install/

And it is better if you use Pycharm or vscode, don't use Jupiter Notebook. And if you don't have python on your computer you can install from the Microsoft store or from the web.
I hope my answer is clear.