# install a module without pip/easy_install or "python setup.py install"

Tags: python

I am trying to install the ptyprocess module: https://github.com/pexpect/ptyprocess.

I cannot do a "pip install ptyprocess" as my pip is blocked by ssl issues on the server.

Also, I cannot clone the above repository and run a "python setup.py install" since there is no setup.py in the repository; instead there is a pyproject.toml which requires "pip install pyproject.yoml", but again, this is reliant on pip which is blocked.

How then can I install this module?

p.s. I've installed other modules on my server via github, but they have the desired "setup.py" and not "pyproject.toml", therefore I was able to run "python setup.py install" successfully.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to manually install a pypi module without pip/easy\_install?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13270877/how-to-manually-install-a-pypi-module-without-pip-easy-install)

Answer (score 1):

To install a module copy the `pytprocess` folder (or whatever folder contains the topmost `__init__.py`) to your `site-packages` (usually in `{python location}\lib\site-packages`) directory. You may still need to manually install the dependencies, (in this case `flit`) as well. Note this only works if the package is pure python.

Comment: Hi, thank you very much. This fixed my issue. +1. p.s. what do you mean by top `__init__.py`? There are two of them, each in different dirs.

Comment: In python, the precence of a `__init__.py` indicates that a folder is the root folder of a library. A module must either be a single file in site packages or a single folder container a `__init__.py` A package usually has one `__init__.py` for the root and possibly others in subfolders for other submodules. A `__init__.py` in a seperate root folder usually indicates a different related module, possibly for unit testing the main module or similar.

Answer (score 0):

> my pip is blocked by ssl issues on the server

your actual question put aside, you should also fix this issue

---

Coming to your question, if the package you are trying to install is on PyPi (where `pip` usually looks for packages), then you always have the option to manually download it first from the [files section of the projects page](https://pypi.org/project/ptyprocess/#files) and then install it. In this case, there are two files available:

1. `ptyprocess-0.6.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl` - This is a whl file, which is a pre-packed file created by setuptools. It is compatible with both python2 and 3 versions and has no OS restrictions ("any"). Once downloaded you can install using `pip install ptyprocess-0.6.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl`
2. `ptyprocess-0.6.0.tar.gz` This is the source code, it can be installed using `pip install ptyprocess-0.6.0.tar.gz`.

This solution is of course specific to packages that are available on PyPi as a workaround if `pip` cannot download and install the project itself. It also works to `pip install` on offline machines if you just download the neccessary files on a second machine and then copy them over