# Spyder not recognising jira package installed manually

Tags: python, anaconda, spyder

Based on Suggestion given for offline installation instead of PIP and EasyPath , proceeded to download and install all the files required.

Result of pip install JIRA - after that.. just to ensure all the packages are present.

```
(D:\Users\kiran\AppData\Local\Microsoft\AppV\Client\Integration\95FD7873-726E-40E9-B477-CC4010411846\Root) D:\SypderPrgs>pip install jira
Requirement already satisfied: jira in c:\programdata\app-v\95fd7873-726e-40e9-b477-cc4010411846\9727bf3a-f7f8-45a4-ad38-2f35b6e0fb2a\root\lib\site-packages\jira-0.0.0-py
Requirement already satisfied: defusedxml in c:\programdata\app-v\95fd7873-726e-40e9-b477-cc4010411846\9727bf3a-f7f8-45a4-ad38-2f35b6e0fb2a\root\lib\site-packages\defused
py3.6.egg (from jira)
Requirement already satisfied: keyring in c:\programdata\app-v\95fd7873-726e-40e9-b477-cc4010411846\9727bf3a-f7f8-45a4-ad38-2f35b6e0fb2a\root\lib\site-packages\keyring-0.
egg (from jira)
Requirement already satisfied: requests-oauthlib>=1.1.0 in c:\programdata\app-v\95fd7873-726e-40e9-b477-cc4010411846\9727bf3a-f7f8-45a4-ad38-2f35b6e0fb2a\root\lib\site-pa
uests_oauthlib-1.2.0-py3.6.egg (from jira)
Requirement already satisfied: requests>=2.10.0 in c:\programdata\app-v\95fd7873-726e-40e9-b477-cc4010411846\9727bf3a-f7f8-45a4-ad38-2f35b6e0fb2a\root\lib\site-packages (

Requirement already satisfied: requests_toolbelt in c:\programdata\app-v\95fd7873-726e-40e9-b477-cc4010411846\9727bf3a-f7f8-45a4-ad38-2f35b6e0fb2a\root\lib\site-packages\
oolbelt-0.9.1-py3.6.egg (from jira)
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools>=20.10.1 in c:\programdata\app-v\95fd7873-726e-40e9-b477-cc4010411846\9727bf3a-f7f8-45a4-ad38-2f35b6e0fb2a\root\lib\site-package
ra)
Requirement already satisfied: entrypoints in c:\programdata\app-v\95fd7873-726e-40e9-b477-cc4010411846\9727bf3a-f7f8-45a4-ad38-2f35b6e0fb2a\root\lib\site-packages (from
ira)
Requirement already satisfied: pywin32-ctypes!=0.1.0,!=0.1.1 in c:\programdata\app-v\95fd7873-726e-40e9-b477-cc4010411846\9727bf3a-f7f8-45a4-ad38-2f35b6e0fb2a\root\lib\si
s\pywin32_ctypes-0.2.0-py3.6.egg (from keyring->jira)
Requirement already satisfied: oauthlib>=3.0.0 in c:\programdata\app-v\95fd7873-726e-40e9-b477-cc4010411846\9727bf3a-f7f8-45a4-ad38-2f35b6e0fb2a\root\lib\site-packages\oa
.0-py3.6.egg (from requests-oauthlib>=1.1.0->jira)
Requirement already satisfied: chardet<3.1.0,>=3.0.2 in c:\programdata\app-v\95fd7873-726e-40e9-b477-cc4010411846\9727bf3a-f7f8-45a4-ad38-2f35b6e0fb2a\root\lib\site-packa
requests>=2.10.0->jira)
Requirement already satisfied: idna<2.7,>=2.5 in c:\programdata\app-v\95fd7873-726e-40e9-b477-cc4010411846\9727bf3a-f7f8-45a4-ad38-2f35b6e0fb2a\root\lib\site-packages (fr
s>=2.10.0->jira)
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3<1.23,>=1.21.1 in c:\programdata\app-v\95fd7873-726e-40e9-b477-cc4010411846\9727bf3a-f7f8-45a4-ad38-2f35b6e0fb2a\root\lib\site-packa
requests>=2.10.0->jira)
Requirement already satisfied: certifi>=2017.4.17 in c:\programdata\app-v\95fd7873-726e-40e9-b477-cc4010411846\9727bf3a-f7f8-45a4-ad38-2f35b6e0fb2a\root\lib\site-packages
uests>=2.10.0->jira)
                                                                                                                                                    m jira)Requirement already satisfied: keyring in c:\programdata\app-v\95fd7873-726e-40e9-b477-cc4010411846\9727bf3a-f7f8-45a4-ad38-2f35b6e0fb2a\root\lib\site-packages\keyring-0.0.0-py3.6.egg (from jira)Requirement already satisfied: requests-oauthlib>=1.1.0 in c:\programdata\app-v\95fd7873-726e-40e9-b477-cc4010411846\9727bf3a-f7f8-45a4-ad38-2f35b6e0fb2a\root\lib\site-packages\requests_oauthlib-1.2.0-py3.6.egg (from jira)Requirement already satisfied: requests>=2.10.0 in c:\programdata\app-v\95fd7873-726e-40e9-b477-cc4010411846\9727bf3a-f7f8-45a4-ad38-2f35b6e0fb2a\root\lib\site-packages (from jira)Requirement already satisfied: requests_toolbelt in c:\programdata\app-v\95fd7873-726e-40e9-b477-cc4010411846\9727bf3a-f7f8-45a4-ad38-2f35b6e0fb2a\root\lib\site-packages\requests_toolbelt-0.9.1-py3.6.egg (from jira)Requirement already satisfied: setuptools>=20.10.1 in c:\programdata\app-v\95fd7873-726e-40e9-b477-cc4010411846\9727bf3a-f7f8-45a4-ad38-2f35b6e0fb2a\root\lib\site-packages (from jira)Requirement already satisfied: entrypoints in c:\programdata\app-v\95fd7873-726e-40e9-b477-cc4010411846\9727bf3a-f7f8-45a4-ad38-2f35b6e0fb2a\root\lib\site-packages (from keyring->jira)Requirement already satisfied: pywin32-ctypes!=0.1.0,!=0.1.1 in c:\programdata\app-v\95fd7873-726e-40e9-b477-cc4010411846\9727bf3a-f7f8-45a4-ad38-2f35b6e0fb2a\root\lib\site-packages\pywin32_ctypes-0.2.0-py3.6.egg (from keyring->jira)Requirement already satisfied: oauthlib>=3.0.0 in c:\programdata\app-v\95fd7873-726e-40e9-b477-cc4010411846\9727bf3a-f7f8-45a4-ad38-2f35b6e0fb2a\root\lib\site-packages\oauthlib-3.1.0-py3.6.egg (from requests-oauthlib>=1.1.0->jira)Requirement already satisfied: chardet<3.1.0,>=3.0.2 in c:\programdata\app-v\95fd7873-726e-40e9-b477-cc4010411846\9727bf3a-f7f8-45a4-ad38-2f35
```

However when I run

```
from jira import JIRA
jira = JIRA('URL')
```

from spyder - it says ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'jira'
:(

I restarter kernel.. not sure what else to do.. please help.

Comment: What do you mean by "pip is blocked" -- is it not installed, do you not have privileges to run it, is it blocked in the network, ...? If ``pip`` is blocked, then there are likely other common tools blocked as well. Which tools do you actually have access to? What privileges do you have to install tools - such as pip?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to manually install a pypi module without pip/easy\_install?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13270877/how-to-manually-install-a-pypi-module-without-pip-easy-install)

Answer (score 2):

Download the package from github (or wherever the source is hosted). Extract it and run `python setup.py install` from the package directory.