# Add manually packages to PyCharm in Windows

Tags: python, selenium, pip, pycharm

I'm using PyCharm. I try to install Selenium but I have a problem with proxy. I try to add packages manually to my project/environment but I don't know how.
I downloaded files with Selenium. Could you tell me how to add this package to Project without using pip?

Comment: What are you using to manage your environments?

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13270877/how-to-manually-install-a-pypi-module-without-pip-easy-install

Answer (score 2):

Go to File > Settings > Project Interpreter > click the + button and search the name of the package you want to install.

If you want to install it offline, follow the instructions [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSWTQQ_2.0.3/install/t_si_pythonpackagesoffline.html)

Answer (score 0):

open pycharm

click on settings (if u use mac click on preference )

click project

then click projecti nterpreter

click the + button on the bottom of the window you can see a new window search Selenium package and install

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume the name of the project is `JustLearning`

Open `File > Settings`

[image]

Expand the `Project` section and click on `Python Interpreter` and click on the `+` icon

Let's install the package called `randomcolor`

[image]

In the search bar search for the package that you would like to install

[image]

Click on the Install package button and once the package it will show in the bottom that the package is installed

[image]