# Installation of dlib with pip fails on Windows 10

Tags: python, cmake, dlib

I tried a lot to install `pip install dlib` but it always shows an error and I reinstalled `cmake`.

I got the error:

```
pip install dlib
Collecting dlib
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/1e/62/aacb236d21fbd08148b1d517d58a9d80ea31bdcd386d26f21f8b23b1eb28/dlib-19.18.0.tar.gz
Building wheels for collected packages: dlib
  Building wheel for dlib (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'c:\program files\python37\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\hp\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-yynf7mue\\dlib\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\hp\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-yynf7mue\\dlib\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d 'C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-0eyy_3vd' --python-tag cp37
       cwd: C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-yynf7mue\dlib\
  Complete output (55 lines):
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  package init file 'dlib\__init__.py' not found (or not a regular file)
  running build_ext
  Building extension for Python 3.7.4 (tags/v3.7.4:e09359112e, Jul  8 2019, 20:34:20) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)]
  Invoking CMake setup: 'cmake C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-yynf7mue\dlib\tools\python -DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-yynf7mue\dlib\build\lib.win-amd64-3.7 -DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=c:\program files\python37\python.exe -DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_RELEASE=C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-yynf7mue\dlib\build\lib.win-amd64-3.7 -A x64'
  -- Building for: NMake Makefiles
  CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:3 (project):
    Generator

      NMake Makefiles

    does not support platform specification, but platform

      x64

    was specified.


  CMake Error: CMAKE_C_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage
  CMake Error: CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage
  -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
  See also "C:/Users/hp/AppData/Local/Temp/pip-install-yynf7mue/dlib/build/temp.win-amd64-3.7/Release/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
    File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-yynf7mue\dlib\setup.py", line 261, in <module>
      'Topic :: Software Development',
    File "c:\program files\python37\lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 145, in setup
      return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
    File "c:\program files\python37\lib\distutils\core.py", line 148, in setup
      dist.run_commands()
    File "c:\program files\python37\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 966, in run_commands
      self.run_command(cmd)
    File "c:\program files\python37\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "c:\program files\python37\lib\site-packages\wheel\bdist_wheel.py", line 192, in run
      self.run_command('build')
    File "c:\program files\python37\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
      self.distribution.run_command(command)
    File "c:\program files\python37\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "c:\program files\python37\lib\distutils\command\build.py", line 135, in run
      self.run_command(cmd_name)
    File "c:\program files\python37\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
      self.distribution.run_command(command)
    File "c:\program files\python37\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-yynf7mue\dlib\setup.py", line 135, in run
      self.build_extension(ext)
    File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-yynf7mue\dlib\setup.py", line 172, in build_extension
      subprocess.check_call(cmake_setup, cwd=build_folder)
    File "c:\program files\python37\lib\subprocess.py", line 347, in check_call
      raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
  subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['cmake', 'C:\\Users\\hp\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-yynf7mue\\dlib\\tools\\python', '-DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=C:\\Users\\hp\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-yynf7mue\\dlib\\build\\lib.win-amd64-3.7', '-DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=c:\\program files\\python37\\python.exe', '-DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_RELEASE=C:\\Users\\hp\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-yynf7mue\\dlib\\build\\lib.win-amd64-3.7', '-A', 'x64']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for dlib
  Running setup.py clean for dlib
Failed to build dlib
Installing collected packages: dlib
    Running setup.py install for dlib ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\program files\python37\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\hp\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-yynf7mue\\dlib\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\hp\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-yynf7mue\\dlib\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-qzmuuf53\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile
         cwd: C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-yynf7mue\dlib\
    Complete output (57 lines):
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    package init file 'dlib\__init__.py' not found (or not a regular file)
    running build_ext
    Building extension for Python 3.7.4 (tags/v3.7.4:e09359112e, Jul  8 2019, 20:34:20) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)]
    Invoking CMake setup: 'cmake C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-yynf7mue\dlib\tools\python -DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-yynf7mue\dlib\build\lib.win-amd64-3.7 -DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=c:\program files\python37\python.exe -DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_RELEASE=C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-yynf7mue\dlib\build\lib.win-amd64-3.7 -A x64'
    -- Building for: NMake Makefiles
    CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:3 (project):
      Generator

        NMake Makefiles

      does not support platform specification, but platform

        x64

      was specified.


    CMake Error: CMAKE_C_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage
    CMake Error: CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage
    -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
    See also "C:/Users/hp/AppData/Local/Temp/pip-install-yynf7mue/dlib/build/temp.win-amd64-3.7/Release/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-yynf7mue\dlib\setup.py", line 261, in <module>
        'Topic :: Software Development',
      File "c:\program files\python37\lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 145, in setup
        return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
      File "c:\program files\python37\lib\distutils\core.py", line 148, in setup
        dist.run_commands()
      File "c:\program files\python37\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 966, in run_commands
        self.run_command(cmd)
      File "c:\program files\python37\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "c:\program files\python37\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\install.py", line 61, in run
        return orig.install.run(self)
      File "c:\program files\python37\lib\distutils\command\install.py", line 545, in run
        self.run_command('build')
      File "c:\program files\python37\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
        self.distribution.run_command(command)
      File "c:\program files\python37\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "c:\program files\python37\lib\distutils\command\build.py", line 135, in run
        self.run_command(cmd_name)
      File "c:\program files\python37\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
        self.distribution.run_command(command)
      File "c:\program files\python37\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-yynf7mue\dlib\setup.py", line 135, in run
        self.build_extension(ext)
      File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-yynf7mue\dlib\setup.py", line 172, in build_extension
        subprocess.check_call(cmake_setup, cwd=build_folder)
      File "c:\program files\python37\lib\subprocess.py", line 347, in check_call
        raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
    subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['cmake', 'C:\\Users\\hp\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-yynf7mue\\dlib\\tools\\python', '-DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=C:\\Users\\hp\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-yynf7mue\\dlib\\build\\lib.win-amd64-3.7', '-DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=c:\\program files\\python37\\python.exe', '-DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_RELEASE=C:\\Users\\hp\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-yynf7mue\\dlib\\build\\lib.win-amd64-3.7', '-A', 'x64']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\program files\python37\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\hp\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-yynf7mue\\dlib\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\hp\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-yynf7mue\\dlib\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-qzmuuf53\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile Check the logs for full command output.
```

Comment: I got the same error.:)

Comment: did the answer work ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here I got the error that line

`CMake Error: CMAKE_C_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage
    CMake Error: CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage`

- set CMake path into environment variable *(As Shown in Figure)*
  [image]
- Installing Visual Studio build tool latest version 
             link:  https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/#build-tools-for-visual-studio-2017
  [image]
- after installing the Visual studio build tool select the package which needed and download it.
- after download & installing successfully visual studio install `dlib` by commanding in CMD(ADMINISTRATOR) `pip install dlib`

Answer (score 1):

Do the following:

1.go to [github repository of dlib package](https://github.com/davisking/dlib)

2.click on the the green button which has written clone or download

3.Then click on Download Zip

4.after the download finished , extract the zip file and save it in desktop

**NOTE: First intall CMake and then start following other steps.**

5.go to `dlib-master/dlib-master` and copy the directory of dlib-master folder
which for you  should be `C:\Users\(you'r username)\Desktop\dlib-master\dlib-master`, if you followed the steps.

6.Then open pwershell and type `cd C:\Users\(you'r username)\Desktop\dlib-master\dlib-master`

NOTE: IF you have not installed CMake properly , consider installing it , so that you can install the dlib module without any problem.

7.When you changed your current working directory by typing the above command, Then type `python setup.py install`

8.If you have installed cmake, then the package would install easily and flawlessly.

***Answer Updated***

further reading: [How to manually install a pypi module without pip/easy_install?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13270877/how-to-manually-install-a-pypi-module-without-pip-easy-install)

Comment: after hit enter on 'site.getsitepackages()' i get this output instead of any environment directory.

['C:\\Program Files\\Python37', 'C:\\Program Files\\Python37\\lib\\site-packages']

Comment: as I said @ShantanuGupta, choose the second one and follow along the steps

Comment: @ShantanuGupta if it worked; accept the answer maybe; so that other people can benefit from your question.

Comment: @ShantanuGupta, I updated the answer, This should work now.

Answer (score 0):

I executed setup.py as @Moh Vahedi said and got following error in cmd:

> You must use Visual Studio to build a python extension on windows.
> If you   are getting this error it means you have not installed Visual
> C++.  Note   that there are many flavors of Visual Studio, like Visual
> Studio for C#   development.  You need to install Visual Studio for
> C++.

So I'm installing VS now :)

This issue is also written here: [Error in installing face_recognition module using pip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63648184/error-in-installing-face-recognition-module-using-pip)

Answer (score 0):

Downgrade your python to 3.6 
For Python 3.6  everything installs normally

or

If it still not work - use it on linux --- for that you have to enable  Wsl in windows- (windows subsystem for linux ) in your laptop -- then install Ubuntu 20.XX and and install anaconda and use Dlib there

If You still want to install DLib

For installing DLib in  windows 10 , make sure you have installed Anaconda version 2020.02 or above (Released in march 11 2020)

If you already installed anaconda which was installed before march 11 2020, i recommend to uninstall it completely, then install latest version of anaconda ,, and don't forget to check the path option ,

Then install cmake
'pip install cmake' ,

then install
'pip install face-recognition'

go to -- {https://pypi.org/project/auto-face-recognition/#files}

Now download the file with extension .whl --https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/c9/9a/68e57a65018b758e274aed7f0c48808433bd792b73102b516d4f3abb3be5/auto_face_recognition-0.0.3-py3-none-any.whl

*** note over the period this link could change

download this whl file into your folder where your face recognition codes already there

or save it seperately in some library folder

Now Close all anaconda windows like, spyder, jupyter etc

navigate to folder containing whl file  copy the path -                                                                                                           Now go to anaconda prompt - and 
first go folder where whl file is stored - cd [path of folder]  ,    
then run

pip install [wheelfile name].whl