# python - VS code error in installing dlib/face_recognition

Tags: python, face-recognition, dlib

```
pip install dlib
Collecting dlib
  Using cached dlib-19.21.0.tar.gz (3.2 MB)
Using legacy 'setup.py install' for dlib, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
Installing collected packages: dlib
    Running setup.py install for dlib ... error
```

I just simply wanted to download dlib after cmake.
I've downloaded cmake and tried dlib...

```
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\USER\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-8yznfpzx\\dlib\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\USER\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-8yznfpzx\\dlib\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-avg12uez\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\Include\dlib'
         cwd: C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-8yznfpzx\dlib\
    Complete output (60 lines):
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    package init file 'tools\python\dlib\__init__.py' not found (or not a regular file)   
    running build_ext
    Building extension for Python 3.8.5 (tags/v3.8.5:580fbb0, Jul 20 2020, 15:43:08) [MSC 
v.1926 32 bit (Intel)]
    Invoking CMake setup: 'cmake C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-8yznfpzx\dlib\tools\python -DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-8yznfpzx\dlib\build\lib.win32-3.8 -DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\python.exe -DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_RELEASE=C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-8yznfpzx\dlib\build\lib.win32-3.8'
    -- Building for: NMake Makefiles
    CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:5 (message):
    


      !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!     


      You must use Visual Studio to build a python extension on windows.  If you
      are getting this error it means you have not installed Visual C++.  Note
      that there are many flavors of Visual Studio, like Visual Studio for C#
      development.  You need to install Visual Studio for C++.


      !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!     




    -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-8yznfpzx\dlib\setup.py", line 223, in <module>
        setup(
      File "c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 144, in setup
        return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
      File "c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\distutils\core.py", line 148, in setup
        dist.run_commands()
      File "c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 966, in run_commands
        self.run_command(cmd)
      File "c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\install.py", line 61, in run
        return orig.install.run(self)
      File "c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\distutils\command\install.py", line 545, in run
        self.run_command('build')
      File "c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
        self.distribution.run_command(command)
      File "c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\distutils\command\build.py", line 135, in run
        self.run_command(cmd_name)
      File "c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
        self.distribution.run_command(command)
      File "c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-8yznfpzx\dlib\setup.py", line 135, in run
        self.build_extension(ext)
      File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-8yznfpzx\dlib\setup.py", line 172, in build_extension
        subprocess.check_call(cmake_setup, cwd=build_folder)
      File "c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 364, in check_call
        raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
    subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['cmake', 'C:\\Users\\USER\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-8yznfpzx\\dlib\\tools\\python', '-DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=C:\\Users\\USER\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-8yznfpzx\\dlib\\build\\lib.win32-3.8', '-DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=c:\\users\\user\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python38-32\\python.exe', 
'-DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_RELEASE=C:\\Users\\USER\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-8yznfpzx\\dlib\\build\\lib.win32-3.8']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\USER\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-8yznfpzx\\dlib\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\USER\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-8yznfpzx\\dlib\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-avg12uez\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\Include\dlib' Check the logs for full command output.
```

checked here a bit and saw a solution actually: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63648302/13692454

But here is new problem, I am using VS code and even if I download C++ extentions, it doesn't fix. I have no idea to what to do. How can i fix this? Thanks in advance*

Comment: I've download c++ build tools from vs installer. (https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-msvc), and still not working :(

Comment: Hey did u find the solution ?

Comment: Nope, I finished my code from google colab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just used google colab to fix this problem. Can't find a solution for VS code...