# Error in installing python face_recognition

Tags: python, face-recognition

I have installed Python 3.7.8. in my machine. When I tried to install python face_recognition library I got some errors which telling that need to install cmake and visual c++. Then I installed cmake and visual c++ 2015-2019. But I still get the following errors when I try to install.
Please help me to solve this.

```
C:\Users\prasa>pip3 install face_recognition
Collecting face_recognition
  Using cached face_recognition-1.3.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (15 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: face-recognition-models>=0.3.0 in c:\users\prasa\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages (from face_recognition) (0.3.0)
Requirement already satisfied numpy in c:\users\prasa\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages (from face_recognition) (1.18.5)
Requirement already satisfied: Pillow in c:\users\prasa\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages (from face_recognition) (7.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: Click>=6.0 in c:\users\prasa\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages (from face_recognition) (7.1.2)
Collecting dlib>=19.7
  Using cached dlib-19.21.0.tar.gz (3.2 MB)
Building wheels for collected packages: dlib
  Building wheel for dlib (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'c:\users\prasa\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\prasa\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-08cdgdia\\dlib\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\prasa\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-08cdgdia\\dlib\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d 'C:\Users\prasa\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-y5alb_6d'
       cwd: C:\Users\prasa\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-08cdgdia\dlib\
  Complete output (58 lines):
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  package init file 'tools\python\dlib\__init__.py' not found (or not a regular file)
  running build_ext
  Building extension for Python 3.7.8 (tags/v3.7.8:4b47a5b6ba, Jun 28 2020, 08:53:46) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)]
  Invoking CMake setup: 'cmake C:\Users\prasa\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-08cdgdia\dlib\tools\python -DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=C:\Users\prasa\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-08cdgdia\dlib\build\lib.win-amd64-3.7 -DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=c:\users\prasa\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\python.exe -DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_RELEASE=C:\Users\prasa\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-08cdgdia\dlib\build\lib.win-amd64-3.7 -A x64'
  -- Building for: NMake Makefiles
  CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:5 (message):

    !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
    You must use Visual Studio to build a python extension on windows.  If you
    are getting this error it means you have not installed Visual C++.  Note
    that there are many flavors of Visual Studio, like Visual Studio for C#
    development.  You need to install Visual Studio for C++.
    !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

  -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
    File "C:\Users\prasa\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-08cdgdia\dlib\setup.py", line 262, in <module>
      'Topic :: Software Development',
    File "c:\users\prasa\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 144, in setup
      return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
    File "c:\users\prasa\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\distutils\core.py", line 148, in setup
      dist.run_commands()
    File "c:\users\prasa\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 966, in run_commands
      self.run_command(cmd)
    File "c:\users\prasa\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "c:\users\prasa\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\wheel\bdist_wheel.py", line 290, in run
      self.run_command('build')
    File "c:\users\prasa\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
      self.distribution.run_command(command)
    File "c:\users\prasa\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "c:\users\prasa\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\distutils\command\build.py", line 135, in run
      self.run_command(cmd_name)
    File "c:\users\prasa\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
      self.distribution.run_command(command)
    File "c:\users\prasa\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "C:\Users\prasa\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-08cdgdia\dlib\setup.py", line 135, in run
      self.build_extension(ext)
    File "C:\Users\prasa\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-08cdgdia\dlib\setup.py", line 172, in build_extension
      subprocess.check_call(cmake_setup, cwd=build_folder)
    File "c:\users\prasa\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\subprocess.py", line 363, in check_call
      raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
  subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['cmake', 'C:\\Users\\prasa\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-08cdgdia\\dlib\\tools\\python', '-DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=C:\\Users\\prasa\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-08cdgdia\\dlib\\build\\lib.win-amd64-3.7', '-DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=c:\\users\\prasa\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python37\\python.exe', '-DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_RELEASE=C:\\Users\\prasa\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-08cdgdia\\dlib\\build\\lib.win-amd64-3.7', '-A', 'x64']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for dlib
  Running setup.py clean for dlib
Failed to build dlib
Installing collected packages: dlib, face-recognition
    Running setup.py install for dlib ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\users\prasa\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\prasa\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-08cdgdia\\dlib\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\prasa\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-08cdgdia\\dlib\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\prasa\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-h34wkq_s\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\users\prasa\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\Include\dlib'
         cwd: C:\Users\prasa\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-08cdgdia\dlib\
    Complete output (60 lines):
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    package init file 'tools\python\dlib\__init__.py' not found (or not a regular file)
    running build_ext
    Building extension for Python 3.7.8 (tags/v3.7.8:4b47a5b6ba, Jun 28 2020, 08:53:46) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)]
    Invoking CMake setup: 'cmake C:\Users\prasa\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-08cdgdia\dlib\tools\python -DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=C:\Users\prasa\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-08cdgdia\dlib\build\lib.win-amd64-3.7 -DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=c:\users\prasa\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\python.exe -DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_RELEASE=C:\Users\prasa\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-08cdgdia\dlib\build\lib.win-amd64-3.7 -A x64'
    -- Building for: NMake Makefiles
    CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:5 (message):
      !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
      You must use Visual Studio to build a python extension on windows.  If you
      are getting this error it means you have not installed Visual C++.  Note
      that there are many flavors of Visual Studio, like Visual Studio for C#
      development.  You need to install Visual Studio for C++.
      !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

    -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\prasa\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-08cdgdia\dlib\setup.py", line 262, in <module>
        'Topic :: Software Development',
      File "c:\users\prasa\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 144, in setup
        return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
      File "c:\users\prasa\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\distutils\core.py", line 148, in setup
        dist.run_commands()
      File "c:\users\prasa\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 966, in run_commands
        self.run_command(cmd)
      File "c:\users\prasa\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "c:\users\prasa\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\install.py", line 61, in run
        return orig.install.run(self)
      File "c:\users\prasa\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\distutils\command\install.py", line 545, in run
        self.run_command('build')
      File "c:\users\prasa\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
        self.distribution.run_command(command)
      File "c:\users\prasa\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "c:\users\prasa\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\distutils\command\build.py", line 135, in run
        self.run_command(cmd_name)
      File "c:\users\prasa\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
        self.distribution.run_command(command)
      File "c:\users\prasa\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "C:\Users\prasa\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-08cdgdia\dlib\setup.py", line 135, in run
        self.build_extension(ext)
      File "C:\Users\prasa\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-08cdgdia\dlib\setup.py", line 172, in build_extension
        subprocess.check_call(cmake_setup, cwd=build_folder)
      File "c:\users\prasa\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\subprocess.py", line 363, in check_call
        raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
    subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['cmake', 'C:\\Users\\prasa\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-08cdgdia\\dlib\\tools\\python', '-DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=C:\\Users\\prasa\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-08cdgdia\\dlib\\build\\lib.win-amd64-3.7', '-DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=c:\\users\\prasa\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python37\\python.exe', '-DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_RELEASE=C:\\Users\\prasa\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-08cdgdia\\dlib\\build\\lib.win-amd64-3.7', '-A', 'x64']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\users\prasa\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\prasa\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-08cdgdia\\dlib\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\prasa\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-08cdgdia\\dlib\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\prasa\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-h34wkq_s\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\users\prasa\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\Include\dlib' Check the logs for full command output.
```

Comment: I think you have the same problem solved in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63648184/error-in-installing-face-recognition-module-using-pip) question)

Comment: Yes. Thank you David.