# dlib installation error for Python 3.9.1. How to know which version is compatible?

Tags: opencv, cmake, dlib

I have already installed CMake and now am trying to install dlib for a face recognition project. I have seen some videos and the issue seems to be from compatibility issues. For Python 3.9.1 which version of dlib is more compatible?  I have tried using pip to install dlib, manually downloaded it and still it is showing the following error:

````
WARNING: Value for scheme.headers does not match. Please report this to <https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/9617>
distutils: c:\users\aviparna.biswas\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\Include\UNKNOWN
sysconfig: c:\users\aviparna.biswas\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\Include
WARNING: Additional context:
user = False
home = None
root = None
prefix = None
Collecting dlib
  Using cached dlib-19.22.0.tar.gz (7.4 MB)
Building wheels for collected packages: dlib
  Building wheel for dlib (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'c:\users\aviparna.biswas\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\python.exe' -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\aviparna.biswas\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-1u1dh1_j\\dlib_0e99482dc2db4cb5a05e1507ea95d200\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\aviparna.biswas\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-1u1dh1_j\\dlib_0e99482dc2db4cb5a05e1507ea95d200\\setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d 'C:\Users\aviparna.biswas\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-nx3osnd3'  
       cwd: C:\Users\aviparna.biswas\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-1u1dh1_j\dlib_0e99482dc2db4cb5a05e1507ea95d200\
  Complete output (58 lines):
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  package init file 'tools\python\dlib\__init__.py' not found (or not a regular file)
  running build_ext
  Building extension for Python 3.9.1 (tags/v3.9.1:1e5d33e, Dec  7 2020, 17:08:21) [MSC v.1927 64 bit (AMD64)]
  Invoking CMake setup: 'cmake C:\Users\aviparna.biswas\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-1u1dh1_j\dlib_0e99482dc2db4cb5a05e1507ea95d200\tools\python -DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=C:\Users\aviparna.biswas\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-1u1dh1_j\dlib_0e99482dc2db4cb5a05e1507ea95d200\build\lib.win-amd64-3.9 -DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=c:\users\aviparna.biswas\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\python.exe -DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_RELEASE=C:\Users\aviparna.biswas\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-1u1dh1_j\dlib_0e99482dc2db4cb5a05e1507ea95d200\build\lib.win-amd64-3.9 -A x64'
  -- Building for: NMake Makefiles
  CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:5 (message):



    !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!


    You must use Visual Studio to build a python extension on windows.  If you
    are getting this error it means you have not installed Visual C++.  Note
    that there are many flavors of Visual Studio, like Visual Studio for C#
    development.  You need to install Visual Studio for C++.


    !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!




  -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
    File "C:\Users\aviparna.biswas\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-1u1dh1_j\dlib_0e99482dc2db4cb5a05e1507ea95d200\setup.py", line 222, in <module>
      setup(
    File "c:\users\aviparna.biswas\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 165, 
in setup
      return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
    File "c:\users\aviparna.biswas\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\distutils\core.py", line 148, in setup
      dist.run_commands()
    File "c:\users\aviparna.biswas\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 966, in run_commands    
      self.run_command(cmd)
    File "c:\users\aviparna.biswas\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command     
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "c:\users\aviparna.biswas\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\wheel\bdist_wheel.py", line 299, in run
      self.run_command('build')
    File "c:\users\aviparna.biswas\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command      
      self.distribution.run_command(command)
    File "c:\users\aviparna.biswas\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command     
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "c:\users\aviparna.biswas\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\distutils\command\build.py", line 135, in run    
      self.run_command(cmd_name)
    File "c:\users\aviparna.biswas\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command      
      self.distribution.run_command(command)
    File "c:\users\aviparna.biswas\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command     
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "C:\Users\aviparna.biswas\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-1u1dh1_j\dlib_0e99482dc2db4cb5a05e1507ea95d200\setup.py", line 134, in run
      self.build_extension(ext)
    File "C:\Users\aviparna.biswas\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-1u1dh1_j\dlib_0e99482dc2db4cb5a05e1507ea95d200\setup.py", line 171, in build_extension
      subprocess.check_call(cmake_setup, cwd=build_folder)
    File "c:\users\aviparna.biswas\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\subprocess.py", line 373, in check_call
      raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
  subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['cmake', 'C:\\Users\\aviparna.biswas\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-1u1dh1_j\\dlib_0e99482dc2db4cb5a05e1507ea95d200\\tools\\python', '-DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=C:\\Users\\aviparna.biswas\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-1u1dh1_j\\dlib_0e99482dc2db4cb5a05e1507ea95d200\\build\\lib.win-amd64-3.9', '-DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=c:\\users\\aviparna.biswas\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\python.exe', '-DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_RELEASE=C:\\Users\\aviparna.biswas\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-1u1dh1_j\\dlib_0e99482dc2db4cb5a05e1507ea95d200\\build\\lib.win-amd64-3.9', '-A', 'x64']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for dlib
  Running setup.py clean for dlib
Failed to build dlib
Installing collected packages: dlib
    Running setup.py install for dlib ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\users\aviparna.biswas\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\python.exe' -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\aviparna.biswas\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-1u1dh1_j\\dlib_0e99482dc2db4cb5a05e1507ea95d200\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\aviparna.biswas\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-1u1dh1_j\\dlib_0e99482dc2db4cb5a05e1507ea95d200\\setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\aviparna.biswas\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-prgz7cvz\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\users\aviparna.biswas\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\Include\dlib'
         cwd: C:\Users\aviparna.biswas\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-1u1dh1_j\dlib_0e99482dc2db4cb5a05e1507ea95d200\
    Complete output (60 lines):
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    package init file 'tools\python\dlib\__init__.py' not found (or not a regular file)
    running build_ext
    Building extension for Python 3.9.1 (tags/v3.9.1:1e5d33e, Dec  7 2020, 17:08:21) [MSC v.1927 64 bit (AMD64)]
    Invoking CMake setup: 'cmake C:\Users\aviparna.biswas\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-1u1dh1_j\dlib_0e99482dc2db4cb5a05e1507ea95d200\tools\python -DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=C:\Users\aviparna.biswas\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-1u1dh1_j\dlib_0e99482dc2db4cb5a05e1507ea95d200\build\lib.win-amd64-3.9 -DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=c:\users\aviparna.biswas\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\python.exe -DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_RELEASE=C:\Users\aviparna.biswas\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-1u1dh1_j\dlib_0e99482dc2db4cb5a05e1507ea95d200\build\lib.win-amd64-3.9 -A x64'
    -- Building for: NMake Makefiles
    CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:5 (message):



      !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!


      You must use Visual Studio to build a python extension on windows.  If you
      are getting this error it means you have not installed Visual C++.  Note
      that there are many flavors of Visual Studio, like Visual Studio for C#
      development.  You need to install Visual Studio for C++.


      !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!




    -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\aviparna.biswas\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-1u1dh1_j\dlib_0e99482dc2db4cb5a05e1507ea95d200\setup.py", line 222, in <module>
        setup(
      File "c:\users\aviparna.biswas\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 165, in setup
        return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
      File "c:\users\aviparna.biswas\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\distutils\core.py", line 148, in setup
        dist.run_commands()
      File "c:\users\aviparna.biswas\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 966, in run_commands  
        self.run_command(cmd)
      File "c:\users\aviparna.biswas\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command   
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "c:\users\aviparna.biswas\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\install.py", line 61, in run
        return orig.install.run(self)
      File "c:\users\aviparna.biswas\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\distutils\command\install.py", line 546, in run
        self.run_command('build')
      File "c:\users\aviparna.biswas\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command    
        self.distribution.run_command(command)
      File "c:\users\aviparna.biswas\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command   
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "c:\users\aviparna.biswas\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\distutils\command\build.py", line 135, in run  
        self.run_command(cmd_name)
      File "c:\users\aviparna.biswas\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command    
        self.distribution.run_command(command)
      File "c:\users\aviparna.biswas\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command   
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "C:\Users\aviparna.biswas\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-1u1dh1_j\dlib_0e99482dc2db4cb5a05e1507ea95d200\setup.py", line 134, in run
        self.build_extension(ext)
      File "C:\Users\aviparna.biswas\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-1u1dh1_j\dlib_0e99482dc2db4cb5a05e1507ea95d200\setup.py", line 171, in build_extension
        subprocess.check_call(cmake_setup, cwd=build_folder)
      File "c:\users\aviparna.biswas\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\subprocess.py", line 373, in check_call        
        raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
    subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['cmake', 'C:\\Users\\aviparna.biswas\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-1u1dh1_j\\dlib_0e99482dc2db4cb5a05e1507ea95d200\\tools\\python', '-DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=C:\\Users\\aviparna.biswas\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-1u1dh1_j\\dlib_0e99482dc2db4cb5a05e1507ea95d200\\build\\lib.win-amd64-3.9', '-DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=c:\\users\\aviparna.biswas\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\python.exe', '-DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_RELEASE=C:\\Users\\aviparna.biswas\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-1u1dh1_j\\dlib_0e99482dc2db4cb5a05e1507ea95d200\\build\\lib.win-amd64-3.9', '-A', 'x64']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\users\aviparna.biswas\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\python.exe' -u 
-c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\aviparna.biswas\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-1u1dh1_j\\dlib_0e99482dc2db4cb5a05e1507ea95d200\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\aviparna.biswas\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-1u1dh1_j\\dlib_0e99482dc2db4cb5a05e1507ea95d200\\setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\aviparna.biswas\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-prgz7cvz\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\users\aviparna.biswas\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\Include\dlib' Check the logs for full command output.```
````

Comment: The error message is about **absence of Visual Studio** on your machine. This has nothing common with "compatibility". Quick search for the error message gives that question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63648184/error-in-installing-face-recognition-module-using-pip.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error in installing face\_recognition module using pip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63648184/error-in-installing-face-recognition-module-using-pip)

Answer (score 6):

https://github.com/shashankx86/dlib_compiled

```
I have compiled dlib from source for python 3.9
You can use this
```

Answer (score 0):

it worked for me to install Cmake,dlib and face recognition:

1. First i  Downloaded Visual Studio C++ from this link
   https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/thank-you-for-downloading-visual-studio-for-cplusplus/?sku=Community&rel=16&rid=30005
2. Then I download Cmake,dlib then face_recognition.

[picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Kq93.png)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead).

Answer (score 0):

Just download the relevant wheel on https://wheels.fermentrack.com/simple/dlib/

Example for Linux :
$ pip install dlib-19.22.0-cp39-cp39-linux_x86_64.whl

Example for windows :
C:\> pip install dlib-19.22.99-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl