# Is there an effective way to install 'pip', 'modules' and 'dependencies' in an offline environment?

Tags: python, pip

The computer on which I want to install pip and modules is a secure offline environment.
Only Python 2.7 is installed on this computers(centos and ubuntu).
To run the source code I coded, I need another module.

But neither pip nor module is installed.

It looks like i need pip to install all of dependency files.
But I don't know how to install pip offline.
and i have no idea how to install the module offline without pip.

The only network connected is pypi from the my nexus3 repository.

Is there a good way?

Would it be better to install pip and install modules?
Would it be better to just install the module without installing pip?

Comment: Solution is already here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13270877/how-to-manually-install-a-pypi-module-without-pip-easy-install

Comment: Or search for local copy here: https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14447068/7976758

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+offline

Answer (score 0):

You need to download all necessary packages from [PyPI](https://pypi.org/) and copy it to the computer where you want to install it

Answer (score 0):

using pip it is easier to install the packages as it manages certian things on its own. You can install modules manually by downloading its source code and then compiling it yourself. The choice is upto you, how you want to do things.

Comment: can you share the URL on how to install pip offline? I do not find well because of lack of search ability... sorry

Comment: if you have python2.7 installed, then you mush have pip pre-installed on your system