# Is there any manual install for stellargraph?

Tags: python, stellargraph

I am trying to install stellargraph  without pip or conda. Is it possible to do that? Please advise other options to install other than pip or conda.

https://pypi.org/project/stellargraph/
https://github.com/stellargraph/stellargraph

Thanks.

Comment: Have you done any research, checked the documentation, etc.?

Comment: Yes there are 3 options given.

Comment: 1. Install StellarGraph using PyPI:
pip install stellargraph
2. Install StellarGraph in Anaconda Python:
conda install -c stellargraph stellargraph
3. Install StellarGraph from GitHub source:
git clone https://github.com/stellargraph/stellargraph.git
cd stellargraph
pip install

Comment: I am wondering is there any manual installation available?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to manually install a pypi module without pip/easy\_install?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13270877/how-to-manually-install-a-pypi-module-without-pip-easy-install)

Comment: I tried, I am getting the below error

Comment: File "setup.py", line 27
    f"{tensorflow}>=2.1.0",
                         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Are you sure the package is meant for the Python version you're using?

Comment: StellarGraph is a Python library.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222092/discussion-between-amc-and-stella).

Comment: Let me try installing from different machine